# Index and match headers by derivative table from a single source table

Tags: oracle

I am working with a quarantined source code and trying to create a derivative table query that identifies headers by special character and match the headers to their list items. My goal to to get the end result into a view on Oracle.

I start with a single table generated by users:

```
TASK_ID TASK_NAME
      1 ******HEADER 1******
      2 TASK A
      3 TASK B
      4 TASK C
      5 ******HEADER 2******
      6 TASK D
      7 TASK E
      8 ******HEADER 3******
      9 TASK F
     10 TASK G
     11 ******HEADER 4******
     12 TASK H
     13 TASK I
     14 TASK J
```

I break it down to two derivative tables:

```
A.TASK_ID A.TASK_NAME
        1 ******HEADER 1******
        5 ******HEADER 2******
        8 ******HEADER 3******
       11 ******HEADER 4******  

B.TASK_ID B.TASK_NAME
        2 TASK A
        3 TASK B
        4 TASK C
        6 TASK D
        7 TASK E
        9 TASK F
       10 TASK G
       12 TASK H
       13 TASK I
       14 TASK J
```

But I am stuck trying to get here:

```
A.TASK_ID A.TASK_NAME          B.TASK_ID B.TASK_NAME
        1 ******HEADER 1******         2 TASK A
        1 ******HEADER 1******         3 TASK B
        1 ******HEADER 1******         4 TASK C
        5 ******HEADER 2******         6 TASK D
        5 ******HEADER 2******         7 TASK E
        8 ******HEADER 3******         9 TASK D
        8 ******HEADER 3******        10 TASK E
       11 ******HEADER 4******        12 TASK H
       11 ******HEADER 4******        13 TASK I
       11 ******HEADER 4******        14 TASK J
```

If I write a SQL with a 'Where' or 'Between' command  with a less than or greater than, the headers capture unintended tasks.

So I am not sure how to do this. If I have to write a procedure, I don't know how as I am new to PL/SQL. I do know C# and VB and other programming, but I am not sure if my approach is wrong.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is task_id guarenteed to have the rows ordered? I.e. can we be sure that `TASK D` belongs to `HEADER 2` and not `HEADER 1`?

Comment: is there a known number of headers?

Comment: Great observation, there is a 'Sequence' field in the original table. I forgot to include that as the index. So the source table fields are "TASK_ID | TASK_NAME | TASK_SEQ"

Comment: At least 4 different answers for your question.. I love SQL! *{:-)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the headers and other tasks are always ordered as you showed - because otherwise I don't see how you'd establish any other relationship - and you always start with a header, then you can apply a ranking to the headers as you pick them out, using [an analytic function like `row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm):

```
select task_id, task_name,
  row_number() over (order by task_id) as rnk
from tasks
where task_name like '***%';

   TASK_ID TASK_NAME                   RNK
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 ******HEADER 1******          1 
         5 ******HEADER 2******          2 
         8 ******HEADER 3******          3 
        11 ******HEADER 4******          4
```

And you can do the same to the non-header records; but here the ranking is the difference between their original order including the headers, and once they have been removed:

```
select task_id, task_name, orig_rnk,
  row_number() over (order by task_id) as new_rnk,
  orig_rnk - row_number() over (order by task_id) as rnk
from (
  select task_id, task_name, row_number() over (order by task_id) as orig_rnk
  from tasks
)
where task_name not like '***%';

   TASK_ID TASK_NAME              ORIG_RNK    NEW_RNK        RNK
---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 TASK A                        2          1          1 
         3 TASK B                        3          2          1 
         4 TASK C                        4          3          1 
         6 TASK D                        6          4          2 
         7 TASK E                        7          5          2 
         9 TASK F                        9          6          3 
        10 TASK G                       10          7          3 
        12 TASK H                       12          8          4 
        13 TASK I                       13          9          4 
        14 TASK J                       14         10          4
```

And then you can join those two lists together using that ranking:

```
with a as (
  select task_id, task_name, row_number() over (order by task_id) as rnk
  from tasks
  where task_name like '***%'
),
b as (
  select task_id, task_name,
    orig_rnk - row_number() over (order by task_id) as rnk
  from (
    select task_id, task_name, row_number() over (order by task_id) as orig_rnk
    from tasks
  )
  where task_name not like '***%'
)
select a.task_id, a.task_name, b.task_id, b.task_name
from a
join b on b.rnk = a.rnk
order by a.task_id, b.task_id;

   TASK_ID TASK_NAME               TASK_ID TASK_NAME           
---------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
         1 ******HEADER 1******          2 TASK A               
         1 ******HEADER 1******          3 TASK B               
         1 ******HEADER 1******          4 TASK C               
         5 ******HEADER 2******          6 TASK D               
         5 ******HEADER 2******          7 TASK E               
         8 ******HEADER 3******          9 TASK F               
         8 ******HEADER 3******         10 TASK G               
        11 ******HEADER 4******         12 TASK H               
        11 ******HEADER 4******         13 TASK I               
        11 ******HEADER 4******         14 TASK J
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7e13/1).

Answer (score 3):

Like Alex Poole (and making the same assumptions), I'm inclined to solve this using analytic functions. However, to me this seems like a great candidate for `lead`:

```
select task_id, task_name,
  lead(task_id) over (order by task_id) as next_task_id
from tasks
where task_name like '***%';

   TASK_ID TASK_NAME            NEXT_TASK_ID
---------- -------------------- ------------
         1 ******HEADER 1******            5 
         5 ******HEADER 2******            8 
         8 ******HEADER 3******           11 
        11 ******HEADER 4******
```

With this data, the next step becomes fairly trivial:

```
with a as (
  select task_id, task_name, lead(task_id) over (order by task_id) as next_task_id
  from tasks
  where task_name like '***%'
),
b as (
  select task_id, task_name
  from tasks
  where task_name not like '***%'
)
select a.task_id, a.task_name, b.task_id, b.task_name
from a
join b on b.task_id between a.task_id and coalesce(a.next_task_id,b.task_id)
order by a.task_id, b.task_id;
```

Comment: Some great examples here, I will try them both out! Definitely techniques that are new to me. I will report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of solutions, based on the data you originally posted - hopefully you can amend them appropriately for your particular set of data. (I've included two, because one may end up performing better than the other, but I can't say which since I don't have your complete data set!):

(This first example originally calculated the header_id in a much more complicated way, but Alex Poole pointed out that it could be done in the same way as finding the header_name. I've updated it to use Alex's suggestion, as it's clearly superior!)

```
with sample_data as (select 1 task_id, '******HEADER 1******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 2 task_id, 'TASK A' task_name from dual union all
                     select 3 task_id, 'TASK B' task_name from dual union all
                     select 4 task_id, 'TASK C' task_name from dual union all
                     select 5 task_id, '******HEADER 2******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 6 task_id, 'TASK D' task_name from dual union all
                     select 7 task_id, 'TASK E' task_name from dual union all
                     select 8 task_id, '******HEADER 3******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 9 task_id, 'TASK F' task_name from dual union all
                     select 10 task_id, 'TASK G' task_name from dual union all
                     select 11 task_id, '******HEADER 4******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 12 task_id, 'TASK H' task_name from dual union all
                     select 13 task_id, 'TASK I' task_name from dual union all
                     select 14 task_id, 'TASK J' task_name from dual),
             res as (select task_id,
                            last_value(case when task_name like '*%' then task_id end ignore nulls) over (order by task_id) header_id,
                            last_value(case when task_name like '*%' then task_name end ignore nulls) over (order by task_id) header_name,
                            case when task_name not like '*%' then task_name end task_name
                     from   sample_data)
select header_id,
       header_name,
       task_id,
       task_name
from   res
where  header_id != task_id
order by header_id, task_id;

 HEADER_ID HEADER_NAME             TASK_ID TASK_NAME           
---------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
         1 ******HEADER 1******          2 TASK A              
         1 ******HEADER 1******          3 TASK B              
         1 ******HEADER 1******          4 TASK C              
         5 ******HEADER 2******          6 TASK D              
         5 ******HEADER 2******          7 TASK E              
         8 ******HEADER 3******          9 TASK F              
         8 ******HEADER 3******         10 TASK G              
        11 ******HEADER 4******         12 TASK H              
        11 ******HEADER 4******         13 TASK I              
        11 ******HEADER 4******         14 TASK J   

with sample_data as (select 1 task_id, '******HEADER 1******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 2 task_id, 'TASK A' task_name from dual union all
                     select 3 task_id, 'TASK B' task_name from dual union all
                     select 4 task_id, 'TASK C' task_name from dual union all
                     select 5 task_id, '******HEADER 2******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 6 task_id, 'TASK D' task_name from dual union all
                     select 7 task_id, 'TASK E' task_name from dual union all
                     select 8 task_id, '******HEADER 3******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 9 task_id, 'TASK F' task_name from dual union all
                     select 10 task_id, 'TASK G' task_name from dual union all
                     select 11 task_id, '******HEADER 4******' task_name from dual union all
                     select 12 task_id, 'TASK H' task_name from dual union all
                     select 13 task_id, 'TASK I' task_name from dual union all
                     select 14 task_id, 'TASK J' task_name from dual),
             hdr as (select task_id hdr_id,
                            task_name hdr_name
                     from   sample_data
                     where  task_name like '*%'),
             tsk as (select task_id,
                            last_value(case when task_name like '*%' then task_name end ignore nulls) over (order by task_id) header_name,
                            case when task_name not like '*%' then task_name end task_name
                     from   sample_data)
select hdr.hdr_id,
       hdr.hdr_name,
       tsk.task_id,
       tsk.task_name
from   hdr
       inner join tsk
         on (hdr.hdr_name = tsk.header_name
             and hdr.hdr_id != tsk.task_id)
order by hdr.hdr_id, tsk.task_id;

    HDR_ID HDR_NAME                TASK_ID TASK_NAME           
---------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
         1 ******HEADER 1******          2 TASK A              
         1 ******HEADER 1******          3 TASK B              
         1 ******HEADER 1******          4 TASK C              
         5 ******HEADER 2******          6 TASK D              
         5 ******HEADER 2******          7 TASK E              
         8 ******HEADER 3******          9 TASK F              
         8 ******HEADER 3******         10 TASK G              
        11 ******HEADER 4******         12 TASK H              
        11 ******HEADER 4******         13 TASK I              
        11 ******HEADER 4******         14 TASK J
```

Comment: I like that your first version only has to hit the table once; but [you can simplify it a bit](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7e13/3) to a single CTE by repeating the last_value/case clauses?

Comment: Aha! Yes, that would be much better! Dunno why my brain couldn't make that leap... need more caffeine *{;-) I'll update my answer to switch to that solution - with credit, ofc!

Comment: Don't know why my brain didn't make the leap to last_value at all, despite being slightly uneasy about hitting the table twice *8-)

Comment: *{:-) To be fair, sometimes it's more efficient to hit the table twice than to do multiple analytic functions (something I was uneasy about in my original solution!); difficult to say without knowing the table structure and data involved